# Find average of given numbers in input

Tags: python-3.x

I've to create a program that computes the average of a collection of values entered by the user. The user will enter 0 as a sentinel value to indicate that no further values will be provided. The program should display an appropriate error message if the first value entered by the user is 0.

Note: Number of inputs by the user can vary. Also, 0 marks the end of the 
      input it should not be included in the average

```
x = int(input("Enter Values\n"))
num = 1
count = 0
sum = 0.0

if x == 0:
  print("Program exits")
  exit()
while (x>0):
  sum += num
  count += 1
avg = (sum/(count-1))
print("Average: {}".format(avg))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should probably be asking for input inside of the loop though. You only ever ask for a single number.

Answer (score 1):

You were not taking input inside while loop. You were taking input on the first line for once. So your program was not taking input repeatedly.
You may be looking for this -

```
sum = 0.0
count = 0
while(1):
    x=int(input("Enter Values: "))
    if x == 0:
        print("End of input.")
        break;
    sum+=x;
    count+=1;
if count == 0:
    print("No input given")
else:
    avg = sum/count;
    print("Average is - ",avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because `int` function expect only one number.
If you insert the numbers one by one, the following code works:

```
num = int(input("Enter a value: "))
count = 0
sum = 0.0

if num <= 0:
  print("Program exits")
  exit()
while (num>=0):
  sum += num
  count += 1
  num = int(input("Enter a value: "))
avg = (sum/count)
print(f"Average: {avg}")
```